# Does Microsoft implement "Windows Defender"-like security for WSL 2 instances?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm not certain whether WSL 2 instances, running in Hyper-V, are actually scanned by Windows Defender.

I have found some articles on Google describing Window Defender's performance impact on WSL, but they are not mentioning whether they are talking about WSL 1 or WSL 2.

Indeed, it's possible for Windows Defender to scan WSL 1 instances, since they aare user-space processes running in Windows, and their file systems are rooted at folders (e.g. `C:\path\to\wsl1\dist`)

However, does Microsoft implement any "Windows Defender"-like security for WSL 2 instances?

Indeed, Windows Defender running in Windows cannot scan WSL 2 instances, since they are both running in Hyper-V. So, does Microsoft run any "Windows Defender"-like process in WSL 2 instances? Does Hyper-V perform any kind of monitoring of WSL 2 instances?

Comment: “since they are both running in Hyper-V” - **This is absolutely false.**

Comment: @Ramhound - please elaborate. If WSL 2 is used, then both the Linux distro and Windows are running on top Hyper-V. WSL 2 cannot be used without virtualization.

Comment: **WSL 2 doesn’t use Hyper-V**. If it did then Windows 10 Home would not be able to use it which definitely isn’t the case.

Comment: WSL 2 requires `Virtual Machine Platform` not `Hyper-V`

Comment: @Ramhound - You are right. Still "Virtual Machine Platform" implies Hyper-V doesn't it? See here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/

Comment: Hyper-V cannot be enabled on Windows 10 Home. WSL 2 does **NOT** use Hyper-V.  The entire premise of your question is based on the fact Windows Defender cannot scan the files contained within a WSL 2 instance because of Hyper-V,which due to the fact it using an entirely different optional Windows feature, is actually false.  You didn't provide the articles you read, so I can't comment on the accuracy of those articles, since I have not read them.  Yes; WSL 2 is a major upgrade. It is indeed running a real Linux kernel.  However, it didn't lose features, only gained them.

Comment: WSL2 does use Hyper-V according to Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq  "The newest version of WSL uses Hyper-V architecture to enable its virtualization"

Comment: I would find it very unlikely that Windows Defender operates in VMs like WSL 2.  It would not be able to operate efficiently without tight integration with the Linux kernel.  I would also say that it probably doesn't matter and most people do not generally consider anti-malware software necessary for Linux systems.

Comment: @Ramhound - will you comment on essjae comment?

Comment: @Shuzheng - I already did twice.  That is an incomplete quote.  “This architecture will be available in the 'Virtual Machine Platform' optional component.”

Comment: “While WSL 2 does use a VM, it is managed and run behind the scenes, leaving you with the same user experience as WSL 1.” - This means of Windows Defender was able to scan files within a WSL 1 instance then it will continue to scan those same files once it’s upgraded to a WSL 2 instance.  I will repeat that while WSL 2 is indeed a virtual machine it’s not a typical VM.  By the strictest definition is not actually a Hyper-V VM.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have tested Windows Defender scans, and I can tell that while Windows detects malware immediately, like Mimikatz, it's not detected by the Linux instance. So, there is somewhat a difference. It was detected on WSL 1. I'm interested in this, because I need to evaluate whether to allow WSL 2 for my company.

Comment: If you manually navigate to the WSL directory and initiate a scan.  Does it detect the malware?

Comment: @Ramhound - I will test that. Still, that Defender behaviour is not as good as what I'm used to in Windows. Can you provide any documentation on your claim: "*WSL 2 requires `Virtual Machine Platform` not `Hyper-V`*" - I really can't find anything, but is eager to learn more.

Comment: It's still using Hyper-V as a back end, my quote is not incomplete, "The newest version of WSL uses Hyper-V architecture to enable its virtualization. This architecture will be available in the 'Virtual Machine Platform' optional component. "  Hyper-V just like the "Virtual Machine Platform" are optional components...that doesn't mean WSL2 is "optionally" using Hyper-V, it is using Hyper-V architecture in the Virtual Machine Platform.

Comment: @essjae - can you say what the difference is between "Hyper-V" and "Virtual Machine Platform" optional components? Accorrding to Wikipedia's WSL article: "*Microsoft has opted for virtualization through a highly optimized subset of Hyper-V features*", so is Virtual Machine Platform a set of Hyper-V components optimized for a specialized purpose (I find any good documention on the Virtual Machine Platform)?